# Identify date before event by id

Tags: r, date

I have a data set where I want identify if an invite (Event = 0) was sent before an event (Event = 1) by ID. An invite is considered sent if the invite is on the same day or the invite (date) is at most 14 weeks before the event. When an event happens this process resets.

Here is an example of my data frame:

```
   ID       Date Event
1   1 2017-01-01     0
2   1 2017-01-02     0
3   1 2017-01-03     0
4   1 2017-01-04     1
5   4 2017-01-03     1
6   4 2017-01-03     0
7   4 2017-01-06     1
8   4 2017-01-04     0
9   4 2017-01-05     0
10  5 2017-02-01     0
11  5 2018-01-02     1
12  7 2018-01-03     1
```

This is the result I would like:

```
   ID       Date Event Sent
1   1 2017-01-01     0    0
2   1 2017-01-02     0    0
3   1 2017-01-03     0    0
4   1 2017-01-04     1    1
5   4 2017-01-03     1    1
6   4 2017-01-03     0    0
7   4 2017-01-06     1    1
8   4 2017-01-04     0    0
9   4 2017-01-05     0    0
10  5 2017-02-01     0    0
11  5 2018-01-02     1    0
12  7 2018-01-03     1    0
```

Initial data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("1", 4), rep("4", 5), c("5", "5"), "7"), Date = c(seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-01-4'), by = 'days'), c(as.Date('2017-01-3'), as.Date('2017-01-3')), as.Date('2017-01-06'), as.Date('2017-01-4'), as.Date('2017-01-5'), c(as.Date("2017-02-01"), as.Date('2018-01-02'), as.Date('2018-01-03'))), Event = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

Result data frame:

```
result_df <-  data.frame(ID = c(rep("1", 4), rep("4", 5), c("5", "5"), "7"), Date = c(seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-01-4'), by = 'days'), c(as.Date('2017-01-3'), as.Date('2017-01-3')), as.Date('2017-01-06'), as.Date('2017-01-4'), as.Date('2017-01-5'), c(as.Date("2017-02-01"), as.Date('2018-01-02'), as.Date('2018-01-03'))), Event = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Sent = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("weeks7ago", "Sent") := .(Date - 14 * 7, 0L)]
df[Event==1L, Sent := 
    df[Event==0L][.SD, on=.(ID, Date>=weeks7ago), by=.EACHI, .N>0L]$V1]
```

output:

```
    ID       Date Event  weeks7ago Sent
 1:  1 2017-01-01     0 2016-09-25    0
 2:  1 2017-01-02     0 2016-09-26    0
 3:  1 2017-01-03     0 2016-09-27    0
 4:  1 2017-01-04     1 2016-09-28    1
 5:  4 2017-01-03     1 2016-09-27    1
 6:  4 2017-01-03     0 2016-09-27    0
 7:  4 2017-01-06     1 2016-09-30    1
 8:  4 2017-01-04     0 2016-09-28    0
 9:  4 2017-01-05     0 2016-09-29    0
10:  5 2017-02-01     0 2016-10-26    0
11:  5 2018-01-02     1 2017-09-26    0
12:  7 2018-01-03     1 2017-09-27    0
```

Thanks so much for posting the code to create the data so that it saves us time.

Comment: Nice option with the .EACHI